# Error while creating any view i.e. Button, TextView or EditText

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I am trying to create a simple layout using Button and EditText using the following code :

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/txt_username"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_OK"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent""
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/OK" />
```

But whenever, I try to create it I get stuck because of the error.

When I try to creat an EditText this error comes :

"Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
    - This text field does not specify an inputType "

and for Button :

"Element type "Button" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"."

I tried to remove it using the answer given in the post

[Element type "Button" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371281/element-type-button-must-be-followed-by-either-attribute-specifications-o)

but after doing that my R.Java file get missing and when I view Problem View in Eclipse it shows no error.

Please help to resolve it.

Comment: Remove the duplicate quote `android:layout_width="fill_parent""` should be `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`. Also specify the `android:inputType="number|text"` for edittext

Comment: Sorry while posting it got included but its fine. The error remains same.

Comment: post the entire xml code and check if your resources files has any errors.

Comment: Okay it worked now. Thanks ! after applying android:inputType="text" it shows no error. But can you tell mein why its necessary to include Input Type as in many examples I have seen that its not necessary to place it.

Answer (score 0):

You have one error at the end of this line, you are 2 double quote:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent""
```

and the string value is in lower case not upper case:

replace

```
android:text="@string/OK"
```

by

```
android:text="@string/ok"
```

and think to apply change in strings.xml

I hope will help you